# How to prepare multi-functioning multicolumn and multirow tabularx/tables with top and bottom rules?

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xfrac}
%\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{sectsty} % Allows customizing section commands
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{booktabs}         %to use \toprule and \bottomrule without error message
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable} %to plot figure
\usepackage{threeparttable} 
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,caption}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" column type
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format=1.3} % default numerical column spec
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{5pt} % default is 6pt
....(some usepackages omited here)
%\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs,csvsimple}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm} % needed for command eqref or Math packages
\usepackage{amssymb} % needed for math fonts
\usepackage[
    colorlinks=true
   ,breaklinks
   %, ngerman
    ] {hyperref} % needed for creating hyperlinks in the docuent, the option colorlink=true gets rid of the awful boxes, breaklinks breaks lonk links (list of figures), and the ngerman sets everthing for german s default hyperlink languages.
%\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl} 
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor {c1}{rgb}{0,0, 1} % blue
\definecolor {c2}{rgb}{0.3,0.3, 0.9} % light blue
\definecolor {c3}{rgb}{0.3,0.3, 0.9} % red blue
\hypersetup{
   linkcolor={c1}, % internal links
    citecolor={c2}, % citations 
    urlcolor={c3} % external links/urls
}

%\usepackage[round, authoryear]{natbib} % needed for abbrvant bibliography style
%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % needed for displaying bibliography and other in the table of contents
\usepackage{graphicx} % needed for\includegraphics
%\imp{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable} % needed for long tables over pages
\usepackage{bigstrut} % needed for the  command \bigstrut
\usepackage{enumerate} % needed for some options in enumerate
\usepackage{blkarray}
%\usepackage{todonotes} % needed for todos
\usepackage{makeidx}  % needed for creating an index
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext} % needed for creating dummy text passage
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[nottoc, notlot, notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % needed for displayng bibliography and other in the able of contents
%\usepackage{figures}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
%\usepackage[T]{fontenc}
\usepackage{rotating,booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{array}
\makeatletter
...
\makeatother

%% page settings%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=1.8cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry} % needed for page border stteings 
\parindent=0cm % for spece of first line of new text block
\sloppy % for writing with hypenless justification (tries to)
%\usepackage[round, authoryear]{natbib} % needed for cite and abbrvnat bibliograph style

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\parindent 0ex
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead {}
\frenchspacing
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{\slshape \MakeUppercase {Multidimensional Poverty Index (MPI) in Ethiopia}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}%This affects the in spacing of my paragraphes
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\theadset{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\caption{Sample}
\label{tab:10} 

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{8 CCCCCC }
\toprule
 Region & National and Regional MPI=(H*A) & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Population in the MPI} &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{ MPI Chronic population} \multicolumn{2}{c}{Population Vulnerable to MPI}\\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(l){5-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-8} 
& Svy Yrs & Index & Headcount & Intensity  & XXX & YYY & XXX & YYY\\
\midrule
Ethiopia          & Z & Y & 20 & 30 &100 & 110 & 12 & 15\\
Addis Ababa       & Z & Y & 20 & 30 &100 & 110 & 12 & 15 \\
Afar              & Z & Y & 20 & 30 &100 & 110 & 12 & 15\\
Amhara            & Z & Y & 20 & 30 &100 & 110 & 12 & 15\\\addlinespace
Benishnagul-Gumuz & Z & Y & 20 & 30 &100 & 110 & 12 & 15\\
Dire Dawa         & Z & Y & 20 & 30 &100 & 110 & 12 & 15\\
Gambela           & Z & Y & 20 & 30 &100 & 110 & 12 & 15\\
Harari           & Z & Y & 20 & 30 &100 & 110 & 12 & 15 \\\addlinespace
Oromia           & Z & Y & 20 & 30 &100 & 110 & 12 & 15 \\
Somali          &  Z & Y & 20 & 30 &100 & 110 & 12 & 15 \\
SNNP            & Z & Y & 20 & 30 &100 & 110 & 12 & 15  \\
Tigray          & Z & Y & 20 & 30&100 & 110 & 12 & 15 \\\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

- However, it's not producing the expected table/it gives errors. Thus, I would like to get you attention and assistance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: @TonioElGringo: I am grateful for your kind assistance! I will take your kind recommendation seriously!  But then, I would like to candidly explicate that the code are not merely for this table-maybe-I should have been selective, otherwise it is for the whole Thesis and there are other details that demand the stated codes.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a corrected/improved code.  I reorganised your preamble, grouping all packages devoted to tables.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, english]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xfrac}
%\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{sectsty} % Allows customizing section commands
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots, pgfplotstable} %to plot figure
\usepackage{array, blkarray, tabularx, longtable, multirow,threeparttable, makecell, booktabs, caption} 
\theadset{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" column type
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format=1.3} % default numerical column spec
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm} % needed for math fonts, command eqref or Math packages
%\usepackage[round, authoryear]{natbib} % needed for abbrvand bibliography style
\usepackage{graphicx} % needed for\includegraphics
\usepackage{bigstrut} % needed for the command \bigstrut
\usepackage{enumerate} % needed for some options in enumerate
%\usepackage{todonotes} % needed for todos
\usepackage{makeidx} % needed for creating an index
\usepackage{blindtext} % needed for creating dummy text passage
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[nottoc, notlot, notlof]{tocbibind}% needed for displaying bibliography and other in the table of contents
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor {c1}{rgb}{0,0, 1} % blue
\definecolor {c2}{rgb}{0.3,0.3, 0.9} % light blue
\definecolor {c3}{rgb}{0.3,0.3, 0.9} % red blue
\usepackage[ colorlinks=true, breaklinks %, ngerman
    ] {hyperref} % needed for creating hyperlinks in the docuent, the option colorlink=true gets rid of the awful boxes, breaklinks breaks lonk links (list of figures), and the ngerman sets everthing for german s default hyperlink languages.
%\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}
\hypersetup{
   linkcolor={c1}, % internal links
    citecolor={c2}, % citations
    urlcolor={c3} % external links/urls
}
\usepackage{cleveref}

%% page settings%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=1.8cm, hmargin=2.5cm]{geometry} % needed for page border stteings
\parindent=0cm % for spece of first line of new text block
\sloppy % for writing with hypenless justification (tries to)
%\usepackage[round, authoryear]{natbib} % needed for cite and abbrvnat bibliograph style

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\parindent 0ex
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead {}
\frenchspacing
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{\slshape \MakeUppercase {Multidimensional Poverty Index (MPI) in Ethiopia}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setstretch{1.5}%This affects the in spacing of my paragraphs
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

\begin{table}
\caption{Sample}
\label{tab:10}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*8{C}}%
\toprule
 Region & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{National andRegional\\ MPI = (H*A)}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Population in the MPI} & \thead{MPI Chronic\\population} & \thead{Population\\ Vulnerable\\ to MPI} \\
\cmidrule(l{1.5em}r{1.5em}){2-3} \cmidrule(lr{1em}){4-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-8}
 & Svy Yrs & Index & Headcount & \makecell{Intensity\\ (k)} & \makecell{Intensity\\(\%)} & YYY & XXX \\
\midrule
Ethiopia & Z & Y & 20 & 30 &100 & 110 & 12 \\
Addis Ababa & Z & Y & 20 & 30 &100 & 110 & 12 \\
Afar & Z & Y & 20 & 30 &100 & 110 & 12 \\
Amhara & Z & Y & 20 & 30 &100 & 110 & 12 \\\addlinespace[2ex]
Benishnagul\rlap{-Gumuz} & Z & Y & 20 & 30 &100 & 110 & 12 \\
Dire Dawa & Z & Y & 20 & 30 &100 & 110 & 12 \\
Gambela & Z & Y & 20 & 30 &100 & 110 & 12 \\
Harari & Z & Y & 20 & 30 &100 & 110 & 12 \\\addlinespace[2ex]
Oromia & Z & Y & 20 & 30 &100 & 110 & 12 \\
Somali & Z & Y & 20 & 30 &100 & 110 & 12 \\
SNNP & Z & Y & 20 & 30 &100 & 110 & 12 \\
Tigray & Z & Y & 20 & 30&100 & 110 & 12 \\\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much dear! That was exactly what I was looking! I am very appreciative for your usual timely and great assistance. Thanks and God Bless!

Comment: Hello Sir, I'm very sorry to bother you again yet,   I have a small request as I want to modify the above table to fit the purpose. Here is the proposed modification: There will be two columns under National and Regional MPI (Svy Years and Index); 3 columns under the Population in the MPI (Headcount (%), Headcount(# thousands) and Intensity of deprivation; and all the other will have only one column and no more subdivision (no multicolumn). Thus, I cordially request for your usual help, Sir.

Comment: I'll gladly help, but I would need a clarification, will `MPI Chronic deprivation` be over  `XXX` and `YYY` columns (and similarly for `Population vulnerable to MPI`) or will they each replace one of these columns (not sure I'm very clear…)?

Comment: Million thanks for your swift and positive reply Sir.  Both MPI Chronic deprivation and Population Vulnerable to MPI will have just one column-Let's say xxx or yyy.

Comment: Did I explicate the issues, Sir. I am just waiting for your help as I failed despite my strenuous effort.

Comment: Please see if the version I've just posted is fine for you.

Comment: I have no word how to express my heartfelt gratitude! Simply thanks! That is exactly what I asked!